# AWS unable to assume role in React via JS SDK, access denied

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, assume-role

I have 2 accounts, one I will call RootAccount where I created an organization and a child account called ChildAccount.

I created a user in the RootAccount called RootUser and a policy in the RootAccount to grant the assume right to the RootUser. I want to create more accounts automatically in the future that's why I limit it to all roles within my children. This is the policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "aws:PrincipalOrgID": "o-xxxxxxxxxx"
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

then I created a role in the ChildAccount called ChildRole with this trust policy:

```
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
  {
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::1111111111:user/RootUser"
  },
  "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
}
]
}
```

where 1111111111 is the account number of the RootAccount.

Then I created a React app with some sample code where I want assume the role from my RootUser:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({ accessKeyId: 'RootUserAccessKey', secretAccessKey: 'RootUserSecret', region: "eu-central-1" });
const sts = new AWS.STS()

const checkRights = async () => {
const params = {
  RoleArn: 'Arn of ChildRole',
  RoleSessionName: 'testsession',
  DurationSeconds: 900
}
const session = sts.assumeRole(params,function(err:any,data:any){
  if(err)
  {
    console.log('err:',err)
  }
  console.log('data:',data)
}).promise()
```

}

and whenever I run checkRights() I receive an error message 403 Access denied:

```
AccessDenied: User: {Arn of RootUser} is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: {Arn of ChildRole}
```

Any idea what I might be missing? Found an Error in my code/policies? I doublechecked the OrgID, ARNs and assigned the proper policies but it didn't help.

Thanks in advance!

Regards Christian

EDIT:

I removed the PrincipalOrgID Condition but it didn't help, I still receive the same error message. I removed the role, assigned the Assume All Rule and waited ~25 minutes. I also restarted the node server.

What else could be wrong? Or does it take longer until the permissions are updated?

Comment: Do you have any reference which says you can use `aws:PrincipalOrgID` in identity based policies? From what I understand it is only for resource-based policies, e.g. bucket policy.

Comment: thanks, I removed the condition, will test it now

Answer (score 0):

The [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_permissions_overview.html) say that this condition key is for [resource-based policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_identity-vs-resource.html). However, you are trying to use in [Identity-based policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_identity-vs-resource.html):

> aws:PrincipalOrgID – Simplifies specifying the Principal element in a **resource-based policy**.

This could explain why your policies don't work the way you expect them to work.

Comment: thanks, I removed the condition and will try it in a few minutes, right now I still receive the error

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of troubleshooting and acquiring the aws dev support plan I renewed my credentials for the user and this solved it